# What is the complexity of `sort_by`?

Tags: ruby, sorting, complexity-theory

I would like to know what the sorting algorithm behind `sort_by` is, and it's complexity.

I'm sorting a nested array, and this is what it does; from:

```
arr = [[0,2],[1,1],[3,5],[4,2]]
```

I sort it,

```
arr = arr.sort_by{|x,y|y}
```

and it becomes:

```
arr = [[1,1],[0,2],[4,2],[3,5]]
```

Comment: Ruby uses an implementation of quick sort. Therefore it is on average `O(n log n)`.

Comment: Usually when you consider using `sort_by` instead of `sort`, that is when you do some non-trivial computation within the block. In such case, the computation in the block is the determining factor of the complexity of the whole operation, and the sorting algorithm itself has no significant contribution. What should matter is how many times the block is evaluated, and with that respect, `sort_by` is faster than `sort`.

Comment: @sawa - as long as the computation in the block is of constant complexity regarding the size of the collection, it would not affect the overall sorting complexity...

Comment: @UriAgassi The number of times the block is called affects the overall complexity. And that in fact determines the whole complexity when `sort_by` is used under a reasonable use case. Even though `sort_by` and `sort` use the same sort algorithm (quick sort for MRI), the former has less complexity than the other. The complexity of the sorting algorithm itself is irrelevant.

Comment: Using `sort_by` is usually shorter, so computation triviality doesn't have to have anything to do with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sort` method requires *O*(*n* log *n*). The `sort_by` method implements the **Schwartzian Transform**. It adds an overhead of *O*(2 *n*), while the actual sorting remains at *O*(*n* log *n*). This may pay out, because the iterations become faster than the original ones.

`sort` should be faster for small arrays, while `sort_by` performs better with large arrays. In theory.

---

I could not resist to benchmark and here is the result. Array size on *x* axis, and sorting time in seconds on *y* axis. The array elements were random strings created with `SecureRandom.base64(50)`. Ruby version was 1.8.7.

[image]

The results show that `sort_by` did not significantly gain over `sort` with increasing array size.